# Python] How to modify the value from the first 'read' txt to 'write' txt

Tags: python, python-3.x

read.txt got the numbers with comma like this.
1,1,1,1\n
2,2,2,2\n
3,3,3,3

and i wanna change the each value by the program and i wanna replace the new 
value to write.txt

I did in many ways but I don't know how to find the comma.

```
infile = open("read.txt", "r")
outfile = open("write.txt", "w")

total1 =0
count1 =0

line = infile.readline()
while line !="":
    value = float(line)
    total1 = total1 + value
    count1 = count1 + 1
    line = infile.readline()

outfile.write("Column,Sum,Mean,STD,Median,Mode,Min,Max\n")


infile.close()
outfile.close()
```

Comment: I really, really recommend taking a look at the `csv` module.

Comment: yeah but before i use the module, i want to finish this way to understand well about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First check out the python CSV module https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/csv.html

But for your original question, if you are reading in a csv file and want to get each "value" you want to split, with something like

```
f = open("someFile.csv")
for line in f:                             # Loop iterates through file by grabbing text seperated by \n
    listOfValuesInLine = line.split(",")   #Returns a list of strings that were sepearted by ","
    print(listOfValuesInLine)              #Prints something like ["value1","value2","value3"] etc
```